# react redux dispatches for infinite time with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, router, use-effect, use-state

I am really having a hard time with this, if anyone could help, i would really appreciate. So, what I am trying to do is, after the listFeatured() is fetched, set the home(setHome) its one of the value. But instead it dispatches for unlimited time. I removed rest of the code similar to below, but still doesn't work.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { WEIGHTS } from '../constants';
import { 
    listFeatured, 

} from '../actions/featuredActions';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


const Featured = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [home, setHome] = useState();


    const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
    const { userInfo } = userLogin;

    const featuredList = useSelector((state) => state.featuredList);
    const { featured } = featuredList;

    useEffect(() => {
        if(userInfo) {
            dispatch(listFeatured())
        }else if (featured) { 
            setHome(featured.featured_home)
        } else {
             navigate('/')
        }
          
  }, [dispatch, navigate, userInfo, featured])


    return(
        <Wrapper>
            <h1></h1>
        </Wrapper>
        
    )
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 100px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`;

export default Featured;
```

Comment: Can you show a codesandbox with a reproduction please ? to understand why userInfo one of the dependency change so often

Comment: @JulienKode, thanks for getting back to me. userInfo doesn't changes but the listFeatured() dispatches for infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks can you show listFeatured function please ?

Comment: Have you try my suggestion ?

Comment: @JulienKode, yes I tried . and it worked. can you have a look at this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73270182/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-map-stops-the-dispatch-from-hap , thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an infinite `dispatch` because everything is done in the same `useEffect`, here is the flow:

- it goes inside the `useEffect`
- you have `userInfo`
- you dispatch `listFeatured`
- it update `featuredList`
- then it re-run your useEffect ***because** **`featuredList`** **changed***
- you have `userInfo`
- you dispatch `listFeatured`
- it update `featuredList`
- etc...

### Use a selector when you [derivate state](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors)

`featuredList` comes from the state and it's use to create `home`. Then home  variable can be derivated from the state and just be a selector, it will avoid re-rendering for nothing.

Here is an example:

```js
const userInfo = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin.userInfo);
const featuredList = useSelector((state) => state.featuredList);
const home = useSelector((state) => state.featuredList.featured.featured_home);

useEffect(() => {
  if(userInfo) {
    dispatch(listFeatured())
  } else {
    navigate('/')
  }          
}, [navigate, userInfo])
```