# cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'), stops the dispatch from happening

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-state, dispatch

If someone could help me. So i am trying to use react-carousel-minimal. For its carousel it takes images array, which I am trying to have through dispatch. the problem is, when i run the below code, it won't run the dispatch at all, and it becomes undefined = no images to go through and then I get the error. Also when I run the code for the first time, it works perfectly, then I refresh it and it becomes undefined. Likewise, If I comment out the Carousel, It works perfectly either how many times i refresh.

```
import { Carousel } from 'react-carousel-minimal';
import { listVenueDetails } from '../../actions/venueActions';
import ImageSlider from '../imageslider/ImageSlider';

const VenueDetail = () => {

    const { city, link } = useParams();
   
    

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const venue = useSelector((state) => state.venueDetails.venue);

    const slideNumberStyle = {
        fontSize: '20px',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    }
    
    

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("bro")
        if(!venue.link) {
            dispatch(listVenueDetails(city, link))
        }
        
    },[venue, dispatch, city, link])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(venue) {
            setImages(venue?.images)
        }
    }, [venue])

    

    const [images, setImages] = useState();
    console.log(venue.images)

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Head>
                <Title>{venue.title}</Title>
            </Head>
            <div className="App">
                <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    <div style={{
                    padding: "0 20px"
                    }}>
                    <Carousel
                        data={images}
                        time={20000}
                        width="850px"
                        height="500px"
                        radius="10px"
                        caption={false}
                        slideNumber={false}
                        slideNumberStyle={slideNumberStyle}
                        automatic={true}
                        dots={true}
                        pauseIconColor="white"
                        pauseIconSize="40px"
                        slideBackgroundColor="darkgrey"
                        slideImageFit="cover"
                        thumbnails={true}
                        thumbnailWidth="100px"
                        style={{
                        textAlign: "center",
                        maxWidth: "850px",
                        maxHeight: "500px",
                        margin: "40px auto",
                        }}
                    />
                    </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
            {/*<ImageSlider imagesSlider={images} />*/}
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    margin-top: 80px;
`;

const Head = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
`;

const Title = styled.h1`

`;
export default VenueDetail;
```

Comment: I don't see `map` anywhere in your code, so you probably didn't include vital parts

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, the map is actually in the Carousel component from react-minimal-carousel package. mainly, data={images} line. Also I have edited with more info

Comment: is your images state have data? if not so assign a default empty array like `data={images || []}` and try to setImages from your response it should work for you.

Comment: yes. Images will always have data as in database as well its NOT NULL and always higher than 2 images. also data={images || []} didn't work @krishnkumarmodanval

Comment: can you please let me know what's the response of images data?

Comment: @krishnkumarmodanval its this ['good-top-best-015.jpg', 'date-ideas-good-top-best-005.jpg']

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your data from array of string to array of object in the form of

```
 [{
  image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/GoldenGateBridge-001.jpg/1200px-GoldenGateBridge-001.jpg",
  caption: 'image caption' // if required
 }]
```

as we can seen in `'react-carousel-minimal'` doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-carousel-minimal

Comment: Correct, but I tweak the package as per my requirement, so that I can use the images array directly. you can compare the code from original to mine here: https://codepen.io/samm-ratan/pen/VwXdvMg     I think there are no breaking changes.